# One condition variable, multiple mutexes

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, mutex, condition-variable

I was watching [Operating system course part 2 lecture 2 video 17](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud923/lessons/3065538763/concepts/34341886310923). In this lecture she mentioned that the data-structure of **condition variable** contains **mutex reference** and **list of waiting threads**.

I want to know if it is possible to use the same condition with different mutexes?

For example: I have 2 wait statements

1. wait(mutex1, condition_A)
2. wait(mutex2, condition_A)  //condition is the same in both

If the answer to the above question is yes, then will these two statements create two condition variables or one? Note: Lecture mentioned only one mutex reference.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on the implementation.

POSIX says:

> When a thread waits on a condition variable, having specified a
>   particular mutex to either the `pthread_cond_timedwait()` or the
>   `pthread_cond_wait()` operation, a dynamic binding is formed between
>   that mutex and condition variable that remains in effect as long as at
>   least one thread is blocked on the condition variable. During this
>   time, the effect of an attempt by any thread to wait on that condition
>   variable using a different mutex is undefined. Once all waiting
>   threads have been unblocked (as by the `pthread_cond_broadcast()`
>   operation), the next wait operation on that  condition variable shall
>   form a new dynamic binding with the mutex specified by that wait
>   operation.

So you can you the same condition variable with difference mutexes, but not at the same time.

With regards to C++, [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) says:

> Calling this function if `lock.mutex()` is not the same mutex as the one
>   used by all other threads that are currently waiting on the same
>   condition variable is undefined behavior.

So it seems to have the same requirements as POSIX condition variables.